# Differentiability of Nadaraya–Watson kernel-weighted function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives

Suppose there are $N$ data pairs, $(x_i, y_i)\in \mathbb{R}^2, i=1,\ldots,N$, consider the Nadaraya–Watson kernel-weighted function
$$
f(x) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^NK_\lambda(x,x_i)y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^NK_\lambda(x, x_i)}
$$
Choose the kernel $K_\lambda(x,x_i)$ as the Epanechnikov kernel,
$$
K_\lambda(x,x_i) =\begin{cases}
\frac 34\left(1-\frac{(x-x_i)^2}{\lambda^2}\right) & \text{if } \vert x-x_i\vert \le \lambda\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $\lambda$ is fixed.

I can show that $K_\lambda(x,x_i)$ is non-differentiable at $x_i\pm \lambda$, and I am aware that the quotient (product) of non-differentiable is not necessarily non-differentiable, such as discussion in [Two non-differentiable functions whose product is differentiable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528897/two-non-differentiable-functions-whose-product-is-differentiable), where although only present a trivial example, so I cannot conclude that $f(x)$ is also non-differentiable. Actually, I found a trivial case, if $y_i=C\forall i$, then $f(x)$ would reduce to a constant function, and hence differentiable everywhere.

I guess the differentiability of $f(x)$ would depend on $y_i$, so I am wondering is it possible to determine some conditions on $y_i$ such that $f(x)$ has the same differentiability as $\sum_{i=1}^NK_\lambda(x,x_i)$, i.e., non-differentiable at $x_i\pm \lambda$. Or in which cases $f(x)$ can be differentiable everywhere (except the trival case I mentioned)?